# Tomcat Spring-boot FileNotFoundException while JSF fileUpload

Tags: spring, jsf, tomcat, spring-boot, jsf-2.2

I am trying to upload the file via JSF 2.2 `<h:inputFile>`. When i run my code on embeded Tomcat 8.0.23 everything working fine. When i try to run it on standalone Tomcat 8.0.23 and invoke `Part.getInputStream()` catching an `FileNotFoundException`.

.xhtml:

```
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formId">
        <h:inputFile value="#{bean.file}" >           
    </h:form>
```

config .java:

```
@Configuration
public class JsfConfig implements ServletContextAware {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean facesServletRegistration() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement(null, 1024*1024*5, 1024*1024*20, 1024*1024*30);
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, new String[] {"*.jsf", "*.xhtml"});
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("FacesServlet");
        servletRegistrationBean.setMultipartConfig(multipartConfigElement);
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

.java:

```
private Part file; //get, set
private byte[] content; //get, set

public void save(){                
    content = getContentFromFile(file);
    //..
}

private byte[] getContentFromFile(Part file) {
    try {
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(file.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOG.error("Read from file failed: " + ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user01/apps/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/work/Catalina/localhost/app-web/upload_650b964a_0ff5_4c2f_8f95_07baba2cdc3b_00000121.tmp (No such file or directory)
```

**UPDATE**
I have tested this error on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Full stack trace can help

Comment: @AlexR: What clues did you expect to find there? I can't think of any one. The message alone along with the config seems pretty clear.

Comment: @BalusC, I am not familiar with all components used by OP, e.g. JSF. I can just assume that server side of File upload servlet creates temporary file that than cannot be found. I'd like to see for example when the exception is thrown: when writing to file when reading from it. For example it could be a kind of FS permission problem.

Comment: @AlexR: It occurs when reading from it.

Comment: @BalusC Should i use tomahawk with `commons-fileupload` to do fileUpload? Will it fix the problem? Maybe something with tomcat standalone configuration is wrong??

Comment: As first logical step to exclude one and other, I'd try specifying a valid temp file location instead of `null`.

Comment: @BalusC I set it on `/home/user01/apps/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/work/Catalina/localhost/app-web/`. The same error.

Comment: A **valid** temp file location. So a location which is fully under **your** control, and not the server's. Note the importance of "temp", too. This is not a permanent storage location. E.g. just `/var/tmp` or so.

Comment: @BalusC I tried also with `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`. It also doesn't work

Comment: OK, this can now be excluded from list of probable causes. Next probable cause is that file is being written by a different OS user than one who attempts to read it.

Comment: I think that we can exclude that problem too because i try to start tomcat on Windows and it cannot happen on it.